# Adding javascript onclick event to php array?

Tags: javascript, php

I recently started coding and I'm trying different things such as PHP and JavaScript. I'm sorry if this question has an easy solution. I couldn't find it anyway.

**Context**
I'm working on a project for school where we need to make a playlist with album specifics in HTML table. The page looks like this:

[Playlist page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlctc.jpg)

**Question**
I have three javascript onclick events. One of them looks like this.

```
<a id="songcolor" onclick="document.getElementById('audioone').src='songs/californication.mp3'; 
player = document.getElementById('audioone');
player.play();
">Play song 1 -</a></td>
```

When you click the anchor tag (play song 1, play song 2, play song 3) in the page I'm building a audio element starts playing. This is working as of now. But in the assignment requirement I need to get the code above out of PHP array and into HTML table using a for loop. How do you go about this?

**What I've tried?**

I've tried a couple of things.

1. I tried to add the onclick event into my PHP array and tried to loop it out using for loop. This didn't work. This is a snippet of the array i'm talking about:

   array(1, "Californication", "3:45", )

This is the for loop i use for putting it in a table:

```
            for ($row = 4; $row <= 7; $row++) 
            {
                echo "<tr>";

                for ($col = 0; $col <= 3; $col++) 
                {
                    echo "<td>" . $multiArray[$row][$col] . "</td>";
                }

                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        ?>
```

2. I tried storing the onclick event into JavaScript variable and using that variable into PHP  array. This didn't work.

Again I'm new to all of this so please help me understand.

Comment: any example of your loops? we might able to figure out where it goes wrong..

Comment: You can't directly combine `php`'s and `javascripts` variables.

Comment: Do you really need JavaScript for any of this? Are you not expected to just output an HTML table (not great for responsive design btw) of song information with embedded `<audio>` tags?

Comment: _“I've tried a couple of things.”_ - then _show_ what you tried. These verbal descriptions are too vague for us to be able to determine what actually went wrong. Please check [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, show the for or foreach loop. In case you are looping the raw data clientside with javascript, you might have hit a closure without realizing it. Show code and we can help better. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should simplify the readability of your code using array elements that are more obvious to you and others using associative arrays. In your case, an array of associative arrays:

```
<?php
$media_array = array(
                    array('elementId' => 'audioone',
                           'source' => 'songs/californication.mp3'
                        ),
                    array('elementId' => "audiotwo",
                           'source' => 'songs/californication.mp3'
                        ),
                    array('elementId' => "audiothree",
                          'source' => 'songs/californication.mp3'
                )
        );
?>

<table>        
<?php
$index = 1;
foreach ($media_array as $mediaKey => $mediaObject) {
?>    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a id="songcolor<?php echo $index; ?>" onclick="document.getElementById('<?php echo $mediaObject['elementId']; ?>').src='<?php echo $mediaObject['source']; ?>'; player = document.getElementById('<?php echo $mediaObject['elementId']; ?>'); player.play();">Play song <?php echo $index; ?></a>
        </td>
    </tr>

<?php
$index++;
}
?>

</table>
```